# Same javascript function for multiple onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a `changeImage` function that I want to be executed when someone clicks on an image. The problem is that I have 100 images which can trigger the function.

The only solution I thought of is to make hundred different id's and hundred different functions, but with this as solution, I can only click one image and need to refresh the page each time I want to click another image.

Here are my codes: 
-html

```
<img id="image" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/pic1.png">
```

-js

```
            <script>
        function changeImage() {
            var image = document.getElementById('image');
            if (image.src.match("pic1")) {
                image.src = "images/pic2.png";
            } else{
                image.src = "images/pic1.png";
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Are there only 2 images? pic1 and 2? so each time you click for these 100 images, it only flips between pic1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

HTML Code:

```
<img id="image" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="images/pic1.png">
```

and the javascript code as this:

```
function changeImage(img) {
    if (img.src.match("pic1")) {
        img.src = "images/pic2.png";
    } else {
       img.src = "images/pic1.png";
    }
}
```

This should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img class="image" src="images/pic1.png">

    $('.image').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("src").match("pic1")) {
            $(this).attr("src") = "images/pic2.png";
        } else{
            $(this).attr("src") = "images/pic1.png";
        }
    });
```

Comment: I like the CSS selector approach here, but keep in mind that the code above requires jQuery.

Comment: The OP's question has a jquery tag.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use unobtrusive Javascript and the `addEventListener` method.

Instead of adding an `onclick` attribute to your html, you can add a generic `class` like `clickable-image`. Then in Javascript, find all elements with this `class` and tell them to listen for the `click` event.

When the click occurs, it will execute `changeImage` and pass in a MouseEvent as a parameter. That event has a property called `target`, that tells you which element was clicked exactly.

```js
// This is the method that will be called when a click occurs
function changeImage(event) {
  // Get the target of the event (the image that was clicked)
  var image = event.target;
  if (image.src.match("ff0000")) {
    image.src = "http://placehold.it/100/0000ff";
  } else {
    image.src = "http://placehold.it/100/ff0000";
  }
}

// Find all clickable images that exist in the DOM
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable-image');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  // For each clickable image, listen to the 'click' mouseevent
  images[i].addEventListener('click', changeImage);
}
```

```html
<img class="clickable-image" src="http://placehold.it/100/ff0000">
<img class="clickable-image" src="http://placehold.it/100/0000ff">
```

Click "Run code snippet" above to see it in action